# A point of view on a simple function. String to Int. It is a bad practices?

Tags: ruby, function

I was defining a function to convert a string to int (i know its already defined). Thinking on, going through a string to the last element, then get exponent by its position (its a function for illustration, nothing else). But changing the value of a accumulator, like:

```
def toIntR s 
    acc = 0 #accumulator

    def hack (s, b)
        return 0 if s.empty?
        x = hack(s[1..-1], b)
        eval("acc = acc + #{s[0].to_i*(10**x)}", b)
        x+1
    end

    hack(s, binding) #actual binding
    acc
end
```

I suppose that a algorithm like this: (it is more intuitive)

```
def toIntI s
    acc = 0
    l = s.length-1
    s.each_char.with_index do |x,i|
        acc += x.to_i*(10**(l - i))
    end
    acc
end
```

So, which could be better? Or faster? Or elegant? Or a good practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I want to say that I'm no expert at Ruby. But I really, really, wanted to share my opinions on this based on what I know.

```
def toIntR s 
    acc = 0 #accumulator

    def hack (s, b)
        return 0 if s.empty?
        x = hack(s[1..-1], b)
        eval("acc = acc + #{s[0].to_i*(10**x)}", b)
        x+1
    end

    hack(s, binding) #actual binding
    acc
end
```

In the above method, you are defining another method with `def`. It is actually bad because it defines another method named `hack` on main when you call the method `toIntR`, which in turn makes the method `toIntR` lose its local scope. I mean you don't really want the local stuffs of the method `toIntR` go global right. In your context, you want to call the method `toIntR`, and the method does what it does using its local scope and then returns the result to you, right ?

Instead, if you want to follow that kind of style I would suggest you use a lambda or a proc (prefer lambda) instead.

And in the method `hack`, that style of using recursion while modifying stuffs outside the local scope of the function ain't good, especially with eval and using a different binding. It's way better to just return the result, while creating and modifying the results within the function's local variables. It simply increases its re-usability and modularity that way.

This is how I would re-write it :

```
def toIntR str 

    hack = ->(str) do
        str.empty?? 0 : hack[str.chop] * 10 + str[-1].to_i
    end

    hack[str]
end
```

**Which one is faster, elegant, and got better practices ?**

Iterative alternatives to recursions are always faster and efficient although they have a few more lines of code than the recursive version, so the second solution is faster.

Second one is elegant. It's pretty straightforward with what it does, and simple. There isn't any necessary parts like the first one, making it faster for a beginner to understand.

Second one also got better practices. Because of not having things I said about right below the first version.

Comment: I like your answer, and i have the same thought about iterative and recursive. But my first goal is calculate the int from a string, without its length. Although, its a price that must be paid (i guess).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely say the second option is better. Using `eval` is almost always a bad idea, except for debugging. It's slow, it's ugly, and it makes code harder to maintain. As for elegance, you might want to look at the `inject` method in the `Enumerable` module:

```
def toIntI(s)
  s.each_char.with_index.inject(0) do |acc, (char, i)|
    acc + char.to_i * (10**(s.length - i - 1))
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand that `eval` its kind of ugly but my could not get another solution. Without using the method length. I forget to say that restriction